# Property 'results' does not exist on type 'typeof jasmine'

Tags: jasmine

I'm using jasmine values to get some useful information for the it results.

```
const resultLeaker = {
suiteStarted: function(result) { jasmine.results = {suite: result}; },
specStarted: function(result) { jasmine.results.spec = result; }
};

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(resultLeaker);
const reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
const junitReporter = new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
savePath: 'testresults',
consolidateAll: false,
filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
});
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
```

The above code has a problem with "results", VB code refers that "[ts] Property 'results' does not exist on type 'typeof jasmine'.

Without results, this code doesn´t works.

At the project build i have the expected error:

```
Build:Property 'results' does not exist on type 'typeof jasmine'
```

I  have to get free of this error, how can i do this? 
Do you have and idea?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?